# While running the program,user must be able enter value in either one parameter out of two parameters provided both cannot remain blank

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, oracle-apps

There is one concurrent program which generates Report in Oracle Applications R12.There are two parameters of concurrent program lets say P1 & P2.

So the requirement is such that User cannot leave both parameters blank.User must enter either value in P1 or in P2 or both.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Oracle Apps. However, see if the following helps.

If you are calling the "create report" procedure (or, in Forms, that might be RUN_REPORT or a similar built-in procedure call), do that only if P1 and P2 aren't empty. Something like this (pseudocode)

```
if P1 is null and P2 is null then
   null;
else
   call the "create report" procedure
end if;
```

---

Or, within Reports Builder (which is something that *will* work), you could check that in the **After Parameter Form** trigger, e.g.

```
begin
  if :p1 is null and :p2 is null then
     raise srw.do_sql_failure;
  end if;
  return true

exception
  when srw.do_sql_failure then
    srw.message(1000, 'Error - both parameters are empty');
    return false;
end;
```

Comment: @Littlefoot-Thanks for your input but its an XML Report and not rdf Report. So there is no use of Report Builder.

Comment: Huh ... unfortunately, I wouldn't know what to do in that case, sorry. I hope someone else will be able to assist.